# IV - aggregation issues?

Tags: instrumental-variables

Let $Y_{it} = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3 + \epsilon$ be an individual level regression. I am interested in the effect of $X_2$ on $Y$ but since $X_2$ is endogenous, I am trying to instrument it. The instrument I found is however at a different level of analysis - that is, aggregate level. While theoretically it makes sense, is it possible to be done in practice?

Comment: Well, the question is whether any possible IV is related with the dependent variable directly and not only through the endogenous variable

Comment: The instrument seems valid (i.e. no correlation with the error term). I apologize, but I fail to see the connection between the validity of the instrument and the aggregation issue I am worried about. I would appreciate if you could expand on your response.

Comment: as long as the validity condition of the instruments hold I don't see any reason why you cant use it. In fact you in the banking literature it is quite common. For instance one such aggregated instrument could be the Herfindhal index which is used to measure competition  and is  usually measured at the district level while the endogenous variable could be at the firm level